# how to access HttpRequest object from child or different thread in Spring MVC web application

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, httprequest

`RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()` throws exception

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
    at com.sbicapsec.managerImpl.LoginmanagerImp$1.run(LoginmanagerImp.java:36)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My code

```
@Override
    public void adminLogin(AdminModel model) {

        Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                        .currentRequestAttributes();
                final HttpServletRequest request = attr.getRequest();
            }
        });
        t.start();
        HomePage.nc.AdminLogin(HomePage.nc, model.getUserName(), model.getPassword());
    }
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>loginproject</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <filter>
  <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.sbicapsec.filter.SimpleCORSFIlter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <display-name>RequestContextListener</display-name>  
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>  
</listener>

</web-app>
```

I want to do this because from my manager class i am calling methods of included third party jars. But these methods are called in different thread.I want to put response of these methods in session attribute so that i can use it in my own thread.

Comment: Call your "manager class methods" from request handling thread then. If you are already doing so, then why wont you pass request object into your runnable, insteed of getting it in static-threadbound way ?
As a matter of digresion, you should rather use thread pool insteed of starting new threads.

Comment: in the new Thread you have no request. I guess you can't do that operation in a new thread

Comment: @Antoniossss  those are not my methods.I do not have access to those methods.When i call these methods,It internally create new thread.

Comment: @AngeloImmediata then how can i get data from second thread to my own thread

Comment: Using `Future` would be a wise solution

Comment: @VivekKumar I guess you have to create a class extending `Thread` class or implementing `Runable` and pass to the constructor the data you want to manage

Comment: @VivekKumar: if i'm not wrong you are inside a portlet, am I right? In a portlet I guess you can't use `Future` as far as I know

Comment: @AngeloImmediata no I am just using spring dispatcher servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that code you have shown is your code called from request handling thread you should do something like this:

```
@Override
    public void adminLogin(AdminModel model) {
 // I assumed that this is in request handling thread

        final ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                        .currentRequestAttribut
        Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //now this might work
                final HttpServletRequest request = attr.getRequest();
                //d o something with the request.
            }
        });
        t.start();
        HomePage.nc.AdminLogin(HomePage.nc, model.getUserName(), model.getPassword());
    }
```

If this is that "3rd party lib" of yours you are talking about, the only way for it to work would be setting `inheritable` thread to `true` because according to spring docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html)

> Holder class to expose the web request in the form of a thread-bound
>   RequestAttributes object. The request will be inherited by any child
>   threads spawned by the current thread if the inheritable flag is set
>   to true.

Comment: as I told before that I do not have access to third party library. Above code is just an example.Not the actual code.

Comment: You see that is the problem, you gave me "example code" and I gave you "example solution". As you can see, its useless for SO community and for you.

Comment: setThreadContextInheritable(true) works for my above code,but i dont understand why not working for 3rd party library

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help.I will share the code if i get it.